# Git fetch and pull with no arguments

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I have a git branch checked out named `foo`.

```
> git status
# On branch foo
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

It was originally checked out using this command:

```
> git checkout origin/foo -b foo --track
```

I want to get updates to this branch from the remote repository. I know that either of these commands will suffice:

```
> git fetch origin foo # ignore the lack of merging
> git pull origin foo
```

**If I omit the arguments to `fetch` or `pull`, will git default to fetching (or pulling) the branch that I currently have checked out?** That is, are the following pairs of commands equivalent?

```
> git checkout foo
> git pull
```

and

```
> git checkout foo
> git pull origin foo
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, whether they are equivalent or not in general depends on which branch you are on, your configuration, phase of the moon, etc.

You can figure this out from the `git pull` man page, as I've described below, but I would generally try to avoid having to work that out by doing: `git fetch origin` and then `git merge origin/foo`.  (I wrote a [somewhat rambling blog post about this](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).)

However, your question is really about the default behaviour of `git pull` when you don't specify a remote or a refspec.  We can figure this out from the [`git pull` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html), and in particular the [`DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR` section](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#_default_behaviour).  This is somewhat tough to figure out, so I've put in bold the only parts that really apply to your question given that (a) you are on branch `foo`, (b) you created that branch as you described in the question, and (c) you haven't been changing your configuration.

> Often people use git pull without giving any parameter. Traditionally, this has been equivalent to saying `git pull origin`. **However, when configuration `branch.<name>.remote` is present while on branch `<name>`, that value is used instead of `origin`**.
>
> In order to determine what URL to use to fetch from, the value of the configuration `remote.<origin>.url` is consulted and if there is not any such variable, the value on `URL:` line in `$GIT_DIR/remotes/<origin>` file is used.
>
> In order to determine what remote branches to fetch (and optionally store in the remote-tracking branches) when the command is run without any refspec parameters on the command line, values of the configuration variable `remote.<origin>.fetch` are consulted, and if there aren’t any, `$GIT_DIR/remotes/<origin>` file is consulted and its `Pull:`  lines are used. In addition to the refspec formats described in the OPTIONS section, you can have a globbing refspec that looks like this:
>
> `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
>
> A globbing refspec must have a non-empty RHS (i.e. must store what were fetched in remote-tracking branches), and its LHS and RHS must end with `/*`. The above specifies that all remote branches are tracked using remote-tracking branches in `refs/remotes/origin/` hierarchy under the same name.
>
> The rule to determine which remote branch to merge after fetching is a bit involved, in order not to break backward compatibility.
>
> If explicit refspecs were given on the command line of git pull, they are all merged.
>
> When no refspec was given on the command line, then git pull uses the refspec from the configuration or `$GIT_DIR/remotes/<origin>`. In such cases, the following rules apply:
>
> 1. **`If branch.<name>.merge` configuration for the current branch  exists, that is the name of the branch at the remote site that is merged.**
> 2. If the refspec is a globbing one, nothing is merged.
> 3. Otherwise the remote branch of the first refspec is merged.

When you created the branch `foo` with:

```
git checkout origin/foo -b foo --track
```

... it will have set the following config options, which associate your branch `foo` with `refs/heads/foo` in the `origin` repository:

```
branch.foo.remote=origin
branch.foo.merge=refs/heads/foo
```

So, if you put that together with the emboldened sentences above, the answer is "Yes, in this situation you describe, when you're on branch `foo`, the commands `git pull` and `git pull origin foo` are equivalent."

Comment: They aren't ever completely equivalent -- see my answer for details.

Answer (score 6):

Even in the conditions Mark describes, when they appear to be the same, there is still a subtle difference -- `git pull origin foo` will not update the remote tracking branch, whereas `git pull` will. This is documented in the manpage for git-pull:

`A parameter <ref> without a colon is equivalent to <ref>: when
pulling/fetching, so it merges <ref> into the current branch without
storing the remote branch anywhere locally`

So in your case, for the true equivalent to `git pull`, you'd need to do `git pull origin foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. The tracking information is saved in `.git/config`.