# Git: What goes behind the scene

Tags: git

I am trying to figure out which commands are executed when I give, for example, `git pull` or `git fetch` command. How the refs are resolved? If I give `git fetch` with two remote entries:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = ssh://a@b.c/path/to/git
[remote "origin2"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = ssh://a@b.c/path2/to/git
[branch "mybranch"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

Are all remote-tracking branches from both remotes fetched? This I can figure out by giving the command, but I want to be able to see what exact low-level commands are executed and how refs are resolved by git when I give a high level command.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-The-Refspec). It's not very low-level commands description, but it will give you good overall understanding what is going on.

**UPD:** Also [there's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860893/git-fetch-and-pull-with-no-arguments) a similar question.

Comment: Broken link, I think it should point to: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-The-Refspec